# ARCADE: PACMAN - I met a beautiful girl 5 years ago. Where did I meet her?

Tags: knowledge, visual

I met a beautiful girl 5 years ago. Where did I meet her?
[image: ARCADE: PACMAN]

#### HINT 1

> No need to use the Monster Points Value

Comment: Is there a higher resolution version? I can't read all of the points values in the lower right hand corner.

Comment: @SQLnoob i added HINT 1: no need to use those numbers :-)

Comment: Some observations: rot13('qenjvat' gur purngpbqrf tvirf `4r 59 43`, juvpu vf 'ALP' va Nfpvv. Fb cebonoyl fbzrjurer va Arj Lbex Pvgl. Vs lbh pbhag gur ahzore bs qbgf va rnpu ebj bs gur yriry naq nccyl N1M26 lbh trg `unzohetre`. Boivbhfyl gur fcevgrf ba gur yrsg ner sebz Fcnpr Vainqref, nygubhtu V pna'g svaq gur zvqqyr erq fcevgr naljurer. Gur erq ba gur evtug vf znlor n svyz erry??? Bevtvany qbrfa'g pbagnva terra qbgf ba obeqre. `706480` qbrf abg nccrne gb or fgenvtug NFPVV)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I noticed that

> Counting the dots in each row of the play area produces 8, 1, 13, 2, 21, 18, 7, 5, 18.  Mapping 1-26 to the letters A-Z, this spells the word "HAMBURGER."

Also

> Following the direction of the arrows in the Cheatcodes box traces out the shapes of some letters and numbers:
>
> [image: 1]
>  Looking up these hex values on a table of ASCII codes, this spells out "NYC."

Finally

> I realized that the red shape on the right side of the board looked just like a place I know (not sure I would've figured this out if I wasn't already quite familiar with the place):
>
> [image: 2]

So I'm guessing you met at

> the [Shake Shack](https://shakeshack.com/location/madison-square-park-ny) in Madison Square Park in Manhattan.

Comment: That is completely correct. One missing hint though: The Space Invaders alphabet spells "HOTDOG". So New York City, Hotdog, Hamburger, Madison Square Park combined points to SHAKE SHACK. 

Shake Shack is an American Fastfood Chain. The company started as a hotdog stand in Madison Square Park in New York City (NYC) and expanded. It is now also Hamburgers.

Comment: Cool puzzle! My only thought is that New York City + Hot Dog + Hamburger would not have been enough to solve the puzzle on their own, and yet the map of Madison Square Park would have probably been pretty incomprehensible to anyone unfamiliar with the park's layout. I just happened to recognize it because I used to work around the corner and went there all the time. Were the red and green dots around the border relevant? I noticed none of them were more than 26 dots apart and thought maybe they would spell something out.

Comment: I tested this puzzle in our (Dutch) companies christmas-puzzle. People actually recognized the drawing to be a map of some sort and scanned Manhatten/New York on google maps for this. Out of 50 groups (x 5 people) there were 10+ groups finding the park on the map. My conclusion: it's doable.

The red and green dots around the border are not relevant! Just random.

Comment: @SQLnoob wow you are the new Stiv here! :3

Comment: Of course a Dutch group would get this - it was once called "New Amsterdam" after all... (Why they changed it?  I can't say.)

Comment: The running theory is that ["people just liked it better that way"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xo0X77OBJUg)

Comment: I came for the puzzles. I stay for the TMBG references.